# Protobuf-net on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-7, protobuf-net

Hey. I came across [Protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) and it seems like a great serialization library to use. Is it possible to get this working on Windows Phone 7? I downloaded the MSI but it seems that the DLL cannot be referenced because it hasn't been created with the Windows Phone Runtime. Is there another DLL I should download to use so that it works on the phone? thanks

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but it IS open source. See if you can try to compile it yourself against the Windows Phone Runtime. Just a thought....

Comment: What's the best way to download the code? I tried using Tortoise SVN but it says that the URL is invalid.(`http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ protobuf-net-read-only`)

Comment: when using TortoiseSVN you only include `http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/` as the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is WP7 support in v2, which is the trunk. This is *not* yet fully released (I have a few bits to do), but it [does work](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/04/walkthrough-protobuf-net-on-phone-7.html).

Comment: Thanks for the updates Marc, I'll mess around with the early version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try compiling the v1 trunk.  But [the author says](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) that a big refactor is currently in progress to support the Compact Framework's lack of generics support.

Answer (score 0):

If you download one of the zip files at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ instead of the MSI. eg:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/detail?name=protobuf-net%20r282.zip

you get assemblies for all runtime versions including one for silverlight 2 which should run fine on the phone (I haven't tested it)

Comment: I tried the SL2 and CF runtimes, but they both throw MethodAccess exceptions on the phone.